# Return json object based on header value

Tags: javascript, json, object

I think this is fairly basic, but I can't find the answers online of a simple way to do this. Below is an object that is displayed on my console (console.log(group)) of the web app I am developing in javascript.

The object is a group that contains an array of objects. Want I want to do, is use the name of the object in the group to return the particular object in the group.

For example, in order to return the array at 0, I would like to insert Washer_Cube instead to return it. At the moment it works if I do the following:

group.children[0];

But I want something like:

group.children.name["Washer_Cube"]

which clearly is the wrong syntax.

Any help appreciated!!!!

```
Yb {uuid: "5FAA0E8A-2423-41A4-BB27-95B0C021F4F4", name: "", type: "Group", [enter image description here][1]parent: Fd, children: Array(14), …}
castShadow: false
children: Array(14)
    0: ha {uuid: "37CAB95F-E817-415F-A0DF-3B90BFA1A610", name: "Washer_Cube", type: "Mesh", parent: Yb, children: Array(0), …}
    1: ha {uuid: "BA931E5D-C456-492F-97FC-D25E64CC5F43", name: "Cube_wall", type: "Mesh", parent: Yb, children: Array(0), …}
    2: ha {uuid: "F0E308E5-5EC2-4989-9331-DDC6CCC07429", name: "2", type: "Mesh", parent: Yb, children: Array(0), …}
    3: ha {uuid: "02FDDF6E-9D8E-4209-AAAE-DA32BAEB2CE6", name: "4", type: "Mesh", parent: Yb, children: Array(0), …}
```

Comment: Not getting exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each child in the `children` array and check if the name property of the child matches the header. If so, you can return it. Below I created a helper function that you can use to get that specific object if it exists (otherwise it'll just return null).

```
function getChildByHeader(children, header) {
  for (let child of children) {
    if (child.name === header) {
      return child
    }
  }

  return null
}

var testObject = {
  uuid: "5FAA0E8A-2423-41A4-BB27-95B0C021F4F4",
  name: "",
  type: "Group",
  castShadow: false,
  children: [
    { uuid: "37CAB95F-E817-415F-A0DF-3B90BFA1A610", name: "Washer_Cube", type: "Mesh" },
    { uuid: "BA931E5D-C456-492F-97FC-D25E64CC5F43", name: "Cube_wall", type: "Mesh" },
    { uuid: "F0E308E5-5EC2-4989-9331-DDC6CCC07429", name: "2", type: "Mesh" }
  ]
}

console.log(getChildByHeader(testObject.children, "Washer_Cube"))
```

This returns the child object as expected:

```
{ uuid: "37CAB95F-E817-415F-A0DF-3B90BFA1A610", name: "Washer_Cube", type: "Mesh"}
```